# Dovecot_delivery transport can't write to maildir

Tags: dovecot, exim

When I was making `/var/mail` backup I screwed up and didn't copy permissions properly.

Now I see the following message in my logs:

```
2023-09-17 03:10:26 1qhiB0-000Jx1-CI == username@domain.com 
R=dovecot_user T=dovecot_delivery defer (-1): 
Tainted '/var/spool/mail/domain.com/username' 
(file or directory name for dovecot_delivery transport) not permitted
```

My `/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_dovecot` transport config looks like this:

```ini
dovecot_delivery:
     driver = appendfile
     maildir_format = true
     directory = /var/spool/mail/$domain/$local_part
     create_directory = true
     directory_mode = 0770
     mode_fail_narrower = false
     message_prefix =
     message_suffix =
     delivery_date_add
     envelope_to_add
     return_path_add
     user = mail
     group = mail
     mode = 0660
     allow_symlink = true
```

And permissions on the actual mailbox:

```
/var/mail/domain.com# getfacl username
# file: username
# owner: mail
# group: mail
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```

I am simply oscillating between exim and dovecot mans at this point but I can't find a good answer.
This `s` looks a bit concerning but as I understood it simply indicates that permissions should be inherited for the group.

I guess I need to find out how `dovecot_user` maps for filesystem user but this is where I stuck. It supposed to be user `mail` but I guess am wrong.

Any suggestions what to read/check?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a breaking change was introduced in Exim 4.94 with regards to tainted variables management.

Technically there is supposed to be way to mark an variable verified but I have no time to read the endless and uncanny complicated manual.

Therefore I ended up with hacky solution:

```ini
dovecot_delivery:
     driver = appendfile
     maildir_format = true
     create_directory = true
     directory_mode = 0770
     directory = ${lookup mysql{SELECT CONCAT('/var/mail/',domains.fqdn, '/', mailboxes.local_part) AS directory FROM domains,mailboxes WHERE \
                   mailboxes.local_part='${quote_mysql:$local_part}' AND \
                   mailboxes.active=1 AND \
                   mailboxes.domain_id=domains.id AND \
                   domains.fqdn='${quote_mysql:$domain}' AND \
                   domains.active=1}}

     mode_fail_narrower = false
     delivery_date_add = true
     envelope_to_add = true
     return_path_add = true
     group = mail
     mode = 0660
     allow_symlink = true
```